# Icon stays after keypress in Kivy

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, touchscreen

After keypress there is round blue icon on the screen and it stays forever...
(screen shot attached).
Touchscreen is working correctly - there is no icon after I press the screen. The problem appears when I use USBKeyboard attached to raspberry.
This icon can't be moved.

Any idea what is wrong ?

[image]

My configuration :
KivyPie + RaspberryPi v2 + OfficialTouchScreen

config.ini :

```
[input]
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Comment: do you have any python code?

Comment: The issue is code independent. Any program / code generates this icon when a key is pressed

Comment: how did kivy app launch?

Comment: Command line is : python test.kv --size=800x480. After that there is no error message on the screen. It seams kivy launch properly.
When I remove line "%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput" from config.ini the icon is not present but keyyboard is also disabled ;)

Comment: is that the 3.5 touch screen?

Comment: It's 7'' touch screen

Answer (score 3):

**Solution #1**

.kivy\config.ini

```
[modules]
touchring = scale=0.3,alpha=0.7,show_cursor=1
```

when I remove it there is no icon on the screen and keyboard and touchscren is working. I hope this will solve this issue.

**Solution #2**

I can also leave :

```
[modules]
touchring = scale=0.3,alpha=0.7
```

So there is only touchring without coursor.